# Check if CD or DVD is blank

Tags: mount, automounting, dvd, optical-media

I cannot mount a DVD, most probably because it is blank, so it contains no filesystem.

Is there a way to be sure that the disk is blank?

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic, may need to be tweaked for others:

```
alias dstat='/lib/udev/cdrom_id -d /dev/dvd 2>&1 | /bin/grep status'

⏵ dstat
hardware reported media status: blank
```

Answer (score 5):

Call `cdrecord -v -minfo`.

If you have more than one CD/DVD/BluRay drive, you need to specify a `dev=` parameter.

NOTE: the option `-minfo` (**media info**) has been introduced 12 years ago, so you need to use a halfway recent `cdrecord` version to be able to use that option.

See man pages:

http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/man/cdrecord/index.html

A recent version is here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/ today, the version 2018-12-06 is recent. Just unpack the tar archive and call `make` inside at top level.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be -msinfo instead of -minfo? I called the command with -msinfo; could you please tell me which is the relevant field of the output? Among other things, I got:

Comment: Beginning DMA speed test. Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), read toc scsi sendcmd: no error
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
wodim: Cannot read session offset

Comment: No, it is `-minfo` that means media info, while `-msinfo` means multi session info. BTW: You are not using `cdrecord`, but a fake command that implements the development state from May 2004.

Comment: @GAD3R So there others that are able to see this problem... Could you please point me to a way how to report this?